# Non-blocking Task.wait in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library, nonblocking

I'm trying to wait for a Task result in .NET 4, much like you can by using the await keyword in .NET 4.5. I just can't figure out how to do it though...

My code (to prove that I'm atleast trying):

```
    Private Function GetXDocumentFromWebLocationAsync(ByVal request As WebRequest) As XDocument
        Dim queryTask As Task(Of WebResponse)
        queryTask = task(Of WebResponse).Factory.FromAsync(AddressOf request.BeginGetResponse, AddressOf request.EndGetResponse, Nothing, Nothing)
        Return XDocument.Load(queryTask.Result.GetResponseStream)
    End Function
```

As you would expect, the GetResponse calls are executed on a different thread, but the function has to wait for the result before it can return. Unfortunately this blocks my main thread until the task has completed and I don't have the slightest clue on how to make it wait without blocking. I don't want to use the Async CTP either because that's just running away from the problem.

What's the secret sauce?

Comment: `the Async CTP ... just running away from the problem.` I would say the Async CTP "solves" the problem. To each his own, I guess...

Comment: Sort of, but the CTP is more like a preview of what .NET 4.5 will bring. Not something that you use in production code. And since it builds on the tasks API, it should be possible to do without, right?

Comment: Well, I've been using it in production code for quite a while, but I also have a very limited user base. :)  The CTP is really more a preview of the VS11 compilers; you could use the VS11 Beta along with the ".NET 4 async targeting pack" to develop a .NET 4 solution if you wanted. It does build on tasks - sort of - but to do an exact duplicate [is a lot of work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no secret sauce. If you want to make a method that returns with the result of some asynchronous operation, you simply have to block the thread until the operation completes.

But there are other ways to achieve the same thing. The “old” way of doing this in .Net is the same `WebRequest` uses: have two methods `BeginGetXDocument` and `EndGetXDocument`. You can then pass a delegate to the `Begin` method that will get executed when the operation completes.

Another way of doing this is to return a `Task` from your method. To do that, you can use [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663.aspx):

```
Private Function GetXDocumentFromWebLocationAsync(ByVal request As WebRequest) As Task(Of XDocument)
    Dim queryTask As Task(Of WebResponse)
    queryTask = Task(Of WebResponse).Factory.FromAsync(
        AddressOf request.BeginGetResponse, AddressOf request.EndGetResponse, Nothing, Nothing)
    Return queryTask.ContinueWith(
        Function(antecendent) XDocument.Load(antecendent.Result.GetResponseStream))
End Function
```

This way, the consumer of the method can choose to wait for the result synchronously (using `Wait()` or `Result`), or it can use `ContinueWith()` again.

When using `ContinueWith()` in GUI applications, you have to be careful: the continuation is run on a ThreadPool thread by default. To run your continuation on the GUI thread, you can use [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx). Or a method specific for your GUI library (`Dispatcher.Invoke()` in WPF, `Control.Invoke()` in Winforms).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can chain the remainder of my code in ContinueWith() calls to avoid blocks?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But don't forget the this changes the return type of your method from `X` to `Task(Of X)`. But if you want to wait on several things throughout the method, using `ContinueWith()` can make your code unreadable quite fast. That's where C# 5 `await` shines.

Comment: I still think it's better than having begin/end methods and event handlers all over the place!

Comment: Thanks again, this is exactly what I needed to know. Everything works smooth now. :)